lldb fails to launch a process
I rely on lldb to fine-tune and study my code optimizations as an applied math instructor, and somehow, probably upgrading either macOS to 10.13.6, or the last compiler suite from Apple for that version of the OS broke lldb. Here is a short fragment. The compiled C object, julian, is unimportant in itself as lldb behaves the same way with every C program I have every written on this machine. I can't say when lldb actually broke as it has been some time since I needed to use lldb. The last time I used it, it worked perfectly, as I have many C programs that were tested when written with lldb. Recompiling the programs does not resolve the problem.  Also, reinstalling Apple's command line tools fails to fix the problem, nor does compiling with alternate front ends.
To compile julian.c and all other C programs I wish to debug:
gcc -g julian.c -o julian

or to compare compiler error messages, sometimes cc or clang, since clang is more verbose.
NOTE: I just reviewed my earlier post from 2018 re lldb and I can see lldb worked for me at macOS 10.13.3. I tried running -g compiled C from 2018 in current lldb, and all fail as reported below. Recompiling with my current mix of tools is ineffective.
$ lldb julian
(lldb) target create "julian"
Current executable set to 'julian' (x86_64).
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: where = julian`main + 22 at julian.c:23, address = 0x0000000100000a86
(lldb) l
   21   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   22       int day, month, year, yearDay;
   23       day = month = year = yearDay = 0;
   24   
   25       if (argc == 1 || (argc == 2 && ((strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0) || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0))) {
   26           usage(argv[0]);
   27           return 0;
   28       }
   29   
   30       switch (argc) {
(lldb) run
error: No such file or directory
(lldb) 

I include this listing as is to show that lldb, indeed, has found and opened the source.  Here are relevant details from environment:
macOS: 10.13.6

gcc: $ /usr/bin/gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-   dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

clang: $ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

lldb: $ lldb -v
lldb-1000.0.38.2
  Swift-4.2

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Please don't say scrap HS and move to a newer macOS.  Configuring a new machine with all of the stuff I have on HS is out of the question, as I have years of Perl and C I rely on in my role as instructor of applied math.
PROBLEM SOLVED: pilot error.  See Jim Ingham's comment re running lldb with -x at start-up, to exclude .lldbinit.  Apparently, what I had in mine was incorrect in the lldb I am currently running, a process launch alias.

Please include the commands you used to compile.

If you run into weird unaccountable errors in lldb it's always a good idea to run the session again but add -x when you launch lldb: lldb -x filename, to turn off reading the startup files.  It's possible something in your .lldbinit isn't working anymore.

-x worked :-)  Here is what was in mine:command alias ch command history
command alias bpl breakpoint list
command alias bdel breakpoint delete
command alias pl process launch -X true --stop-at-entry --
for debugging _qsort, we need to simulate io input redirection.
settings set target.input-path ./sortstrings.txt
here's an example of setting a conditional breakpoint at line 236
br s -f distanceGC.c -l 236 -c 'size==2'  I will remove that pl alias.  Thanks very much :-)
